# JQuery Accordion: Broken Layout with YouTube Embed Object

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I am using the standard jQuery UI Accordion.

One of my panes contains an embedded YouTube video, defined with the "embed" tag. It breaks the flow of the next panes: they don't make space for the embedded video. The next pane starts where it would if there were empty space.

Here's a JFiddle that shows the problem (but for some reason the YouTube video isn't visible there).

http://jsfiddle.net/r4pf1n5y/

The Embed tag is in Pane #2 and defined as

```
<embed align="left" 
width="420" height="345"
src="https://www.youtube.com/v/WBgwuFM92i4"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```

Pane 3 should start below the video, and the header should be left-aligned with all the rest.

Also, is there a better way to embed YouTube videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a div with "clear: both" style just before the div which contains YouTube embedded video to prevent pane 3 appears on the side of pane 2.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4pf1n5y/4/

You can learn more about the clear property in [CSS clear property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)